# Server returns 404 in POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-status-code-404, strapi

I have a project I build with React and Strapi headless CMS (using nodejs). The backend, which is handled using Strapi, resides in port 443. When I send a GET request to any url in backend using http://site:443 I get a valid response, but a POST request always returns an error 404.

I've used an external tool https://reqbin.com/ to test it and got the same results.

The interesting thing is that even though I get 404 response, the route is being handled and executed, and yet gives a 404 response back.

Why could this be happening?

Thanks in advance

Here is the code upon reaching this route:

```
 /**
   * Create a/an orders record.
   *
   * @return {Object}
   */

create: async (ctx) => {

let params = ctx.request.body;


if (params.Sum) { // only if we got a good POST response

  // check secret code
  let a = params.UniqueID;
  var res = a.substr(a.length - 12, a.length);
  if (res !== 'secret') {
    ctx.throw(500, 'SECURITY BLOCK', { expose: true });
    return null;
  }
  var username = a.substr(0, a.length - 12);

  // create validity
  var date = new Date();
  if (params.Sum === '250') { // one month membership
    date.setTime( date.getTime() + 31 * 86400000 );
  } else if (params.Sum === '390') { // one month membership
    date.setTime( date.getTime() + 180 * 86400000 );
  }

  // create order in database
  let today = new Date();
  // extract username
  var n = params.CustomerName.indexOf("_");
  var name = params.CustomerName.substr(0, n);
  var instId = params.CustomerName.substr(n+1, params.CustomerName.length);
  const order = await strapi.services.orders.add({
    userId: username, 
    username: name,
    institutionId: instId,
    sum: params.Sum,
    transactionDate: today,
    validity: date,
    cardNum: params.CardNum,
    cardName:params.CardName,
  });

    let axiosArr = {
        institutions: [{_id: instId}],
        validity: date,
        secret: 'secret'
    }
    axios.put(apiUrl+'/users/'+username, axiosArr).then(() => {return order})

  // return order
```

Most of the code is irrelevant to the question, I was thinking maybe the reason that the response is 404 is because I'm not returning the order object right away, but only after the axios.put?
Unfortunately I cannot test it right now

Comment: can you share additional data like request formate?

Comment: I'm sending the request without any auth. Could it be that the server returns 404 because the request isn't valid? Shouldn't it return another type of error in such case? Thanks

Comment: You have not entered a valid URL

Comment: Hello I edited the question to add code thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the route is well executed but it returns a 404, it's because the response body is empty.

In your code your commented the `return order`.

Add in your code something like `ctx.send({order})` or un comment your `return`

You will no longer have a **404**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with strapi but it doesn't sound like an auth issue to me. Are you sure these routes are set up to accept POST requests and not just GET requests? It's common to return 404s if a user is missing a permission needed to access a resource, to not let the person know that resource exists but without any sample code I can't really say for sure what's happening in your case. Could you link more code?

Comment: Hello Sebastian thank you very much for your help, I discovered that acutally the path is working fine and yet the server that uses this url receives a response of 404, even though the POST request is treated well inside this route.
I added code as your asked thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry I think I missed a key detail to your explanation - you said the route actually executes, so that means your route exists, so i assume the URL you send a PUT request too is the one returning the 404. If it were me, I would try to verify the URL you are constructing `apiUrl+'/users/'+username` actually exists as a route/resource on the server you're making that request to. The other reason you could get a 404 in your case, is what you originally suggested where you don't have auth to view the resource. Sorry I can't be much more help, but have a go at looking into these, good luck!